# How to specify serdes in kgrouped stream in kafka streams 2

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When I update to Kafka streams 2.1 it is saying Serialized is deprecated. How to explicitly specify serdes using groupedstream in Kafkastream 2.1 version.

```
KGroupedStream<Integer, Long> groupedStream = msg.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the JavaDocs point out:

> @deprecated since 2.1. Use {@link org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped)} instead